# looking for regex for name age gender with mandatory spaces in between

Tags: regex

This is what I have but it's not working. I'm not getting errors but I'm also not getting a result, pass or fail.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\ \][(^10$|^[0-9]{1,2}]))+(([\'\ \][(?:m|M|f|F|)$]))*$
```

Comment: We cannot really help you if we have no information about the input, the expected output and the output you currently get. *"It is not working"* is not a useful problem description at all. Please update your question with this information. Thank you!

Comment: Just to add, your current expression is clearly looking for a lot more guff than just "name age gender", so examples of input lines would be essential.

Comment: thanks for your reply. basically, I'm trying to create a field in my form that captures name (preferably any first name "a-z" then a one or two digit age "0-9", and finally "m" or "f" or "M" or "F". I'd prefer it if the regex forced a mandatory blank space in between each condition. So... Bob 33 M

Comment: sorry the not working part meant that when testing in a regex tester, it was not showing any matches even when entering the correct patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's see what it is going to be matched by the pattern you mentioned:

```
=====================================================================
^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\ \][(^10$|^[0-9]{1,2}]))+(([\'\ \][(?:m|M|f|F|)$]))*$
=====================================================================

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(([\'\ \][(^10$|^[0-9]{1,2}]))+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «+»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\'\ \][(^10$|^[0-9]{1,2}])»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\'\ \][(^10$|^[0-9]{1,2}»
         Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,2}»
         A ' character «\'»
         A   character «\ »
         A ] character «\]»
         One of the characters “[(^10$|” «[(^10$|^[»
         A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
      Match the character “]” literally «]»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(([\'\ \][(?:m|M|f|F|)$]))*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 4 «([\'\ \][(?:m|M|f|F|)$])»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\'\ \][(?:m|M|f|F|)$]»
         A ' character «\'»
         A   character «\ »
         A ] character «\]»
         One of the characters “[(?:m|MfF)$” «[(?:m|M|f|F|)$»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

And it is very clear that this pattern would like to match context like:

```
aaaa' ]'m
```

And as you're going to match something like `Bob 33 M` then most simplest pattern would be:

```
  (?i)^[a-z]+ [0-9]+ [mf]+$
```

*which means*

```
"(?i)" &     ' Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
"^" &        ' Assert position at the beginning of the string
"[a-z]" &    ' Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   "+" &        ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\ " &       ' Match the character “ ” literally
"[0-9]" &    ' Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   "+" &        ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\ " &       ' Match the character “ ” literally
"[mf]" &     ' Match a single character present in the list “mf”
   "+" &        ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"$"          ' Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

*Hope this **[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)** could help you to understand the subject.*

Comment: Thanks so much Cylian! Not only did you explain some of the workings of regex, but you helped me with the code too. You're awesome.

Comment: One thing I just discovered. Can I enable this to match a single line or multiple lines separated by carriage return? I've tried this but it's only taking the first line

    (?i)^[a-z]+ [0-9]+ [mf]+\s$

Comment: @user1756546: Surely just use `(?im)^[a-z]+ [0-9]+ [mf]+\s$` instead.